# Sending Form Data - PHP / Javascript / JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I apologize in advance for what I am sure is probably a pretty simple question... but volunteered to update a nonprofit's website and I got in over my head with a forms. I have spent the last two days trying to figure this out - but am still not making headway...  so I thought I would check-in here.

The page has several different elements that are shown/hidden by toggling a 'hidden' class.

When the user checks 'use Gift Aid', a hidden form is displayed to collect their information. When they click submit, I would like it to show/hide the appropriate elements and email the form contents to someone at the nonprofit.

The show/hide functionality works fine. However, I cannot seem to figure out how to get the form to send an email to the nonprofit.

My code for the form is:

```
<div id="myDIV" class="hidden" title="Gift Aid Form"><form id="giftAidForm" action="http://www.tinfinitydesign.com/demo/charolette/wp-content/uploads/php/donateform.php" method="post" name="giftAidForm">I want to gift aid my donation of £. <input id="Amount" name="theAmount" size="10" type="text" /> to <u>CHARLOTTE'S BAG (reg# 1169419) </u>.

I am a UK taxpayer and understand that if I pay less Income Tax and/or Capital Gains Tax in the current tax year than the amount of Gift Aid claimed on all my donations it is my responsibility to pay any difference.

<strong>MY DETAILS</strong>

Title: <input id="Title" name="theTitle" size="6" type="text" /> First name or initial(s): <input id="Forename" maxlength="30" name="theForename" size="30" type="text" /> Surname:  <input id="Surname" name="theSurname" size="30" type="text" />

Full Home Address:
<input id="Address1" name="theAddress1" size="100%" type="text" /><input id="Address2" name="theAddress2" size="100%" type="text" /><input id="Address3" name="theAddress3" size="100%" type="text" />
Postcode: <input id="Postcode" name="thePostcode" size="50%" type="text" />
Date:         <input id="theDate" name="theDate" size="50%" type="text" />
<strong>Please notify the charity if you: </strong>
<ul>
    <li>want to cancel this declaration</li>
    <li>change your name or home address</li>
    <li>no longer pay sufficient tax on your income and/or capital gains</li>
</ul>
If you pay Income Tax at the higher or additional rate and want to receive the additional tax relief due to you, you must include all your Gift Aid donations on your Self-Assessment tax return or ask HM Revenue and Customs to adjust your tax code.

<hr />

<table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="right">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td align="left">
<blockquote><a id="btnCancel" href="#"><strong>CANCEL</strong></a></blockquote>
</td>
<td align="right">
<blockquote><a id="btnSubmit" href="#"><strong>SUBMIT</strong></a></blockquote>
</td>
</tr>
```

My javascript is:

```
document.getElementById("checkit").addEventListener("click", showHideForm);
    document.getElementById("btnCancel").addEventListener("click", resetForm);
    document.getElementById("btnSubmit").addEventListener("click", submitForm);

    function showHideForm() {
        document.getElementById("myDIV").classList.toggle("hidden");
        document.getElementById("donatebutton").classList.toggle("hidden");

    }

    function showHideGiftAidText() {
        document.getElementById("donateText").classList.toggle("hidden");
        document.getElementById("donateGiftAidText").classList.toggle("hidden");
    }

    function resetForm(){
        //Clear data from the form, uncheck the gift aid checkbox, and hide the form.
        document.getElementById("giftAidForm").reset();
        document.getElementById('checkit').checked = false;
        showHideForm();
    }

    function submitForm(){
        //Submit form, hide the original donate text, display gift aid message and display donate button
        //callPhp();
        showHideGiftAidText();
        document.getElementById('checkit').checked = false;
        showHideForm();
    }
```

Their current site essentialy uses a modal, then redirects to a new donate page on submit. However, the theme I am using for WordPress does not allow modals.

That php code they provided is:

```
// SETUP THE EMAIL ADDRESS TO SEND TO, THE SUBJECT and FROM (can be anything)
$to = 'info@charlottesbag.com' ;
$subject = 'Gift Aid Form Completed' ;
$from = 'info@charlottesbag.com';

// SETS UP THE BODY OF THE EMAIL AND INSERTS THE FILLED IN DETAILS
$message = "I want to Gift Aid my Donation of £" . $_POST [ "theAmount" ] . " to:\n";
$message.= "Name of Charity: CHARLOTTE'S BAG (reg num 1169419)\n\n";
$message.= "I am a UK taxpayer and understand that if I pay less Income Tax and/or Capital Gains Tax in the current tax year than the amount of Gift Aid claimed on all my donations it is my responsibility to pay any difference.\n\n";
$message.= "My Details\n\n";
$message.= "Title: " . $_POST [ "theTitle" ] ."      " ;
$message.= "First name / inital(s): " . $_POST [ "theForename" ] ."\n";
$message.= "Surname: " . $_POST [ "theSurname" ] ."\n";
$message.= "Full Home Address: " . $_POST [ "theAddress1" ] ."\n";
$message.=  "                  " . $_POST [ "theAddress2" ] ."\n";
$message.=  "                  " . $_POST [ "theAddress3" ] ."\n";
$message.=  "Postcode: " . $_POST [ "thePostcode" ] ."    ";
$message.=  "Date: " . $_POST [ "theDate" ] ."\n";


$headers = 'From: ' . $from . PHP_EOL ;

//SENDS THE EMAIL TO CRESSY
mail ( $to, $subject, $message, $headers ) ;

// THE TEXT IN QUOTES BELOW IS WHAT WILL BE
// DISPLAYED TO USERS AFTER SUBMITTING THE FORM. REDIRECTS TO THE NEXT DONATION PAGE FOR PAYMENT
echo "<script>window.location.href='http://www.tinfinitydesign.com/demo/charolette/donate-with-gift-aid/'</script>";
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: This might be an email issue rather than PHP.  Is the code that is sending the email on the same server as the destination for the email?

Comment: It is on the same server. However, the original PHP uses a redirect on submit to a new page that I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: The server may be configured to refuse email from itself.  Is this on shared hosting?  Try hard-coding an email function that just sends an email to you to figure out the parameters.  Once you have that working, update your code.

Comment: Embedding the $_POSTs directly in the email, without any sanitization or validation is extremely risky and the form **will** be abused by spammers.

Comment: Is this embedding $_POSTs directly? I'm sorry if that's an obvious question - I am completely lost on this.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very simple sanitization approach, it will strip out any HTML tags with the filter, then it will do a limited check for email header injection.  This isn't bullet proof, but it is better than nothing.

*I have not tested this code*

```
// First set up the sanitization filter
// Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php
$filter = [
    'filter' => FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
    'flags'  => FILTER_FLAG_NO_ENCODE_QUOTES
];

// Prepare an array of the filters, using the same filter for all the inputs
// You may want to spend more time to ensure the data is valid
// The first array is the names of the inputs that are being sent
// Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php
$args = array_fill_keys(['theAmount','theTitle' /*, remaining inputs */], $filter);

// Apply the sanitization filters to the inputs in the array
// Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input-array.php
$inputData = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, $args);

// Loop through the array
// $var is the name of the input, for $_POST['name'], $var would be 'name'
// $value is the data submitted for $var after sanitization
// If $value is false, it was not valid and it was discarded
foreach ($inputData as $var => $value) {
    // $$var is a variable variable, it creates a variable named 
    // From the contents of $var, continuing the example of $_POST['name'], 
    // this would create a variable named $name
    // Note the call to the safe function
    $$var = !empty($idata) ? safe($idata) : '';
}

// Use heredoc notation to make it easier to format the message
// Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc
$message = <<<MESSAGE
I want to Gift Aid my Donation of £" . $theAmount to:
Name of Charity: CHARLOTTE'S BAG (reg num 1169419)

MESSAGE;
```

The **safe** function will strip out email headers.  Put this code in the same file as the other code.

```
// Removes items from inputs which 
// could be used by spammers to send emails from your server
// Ref: http://nyphp.org/PHundamentals/8_Preventing-Email-Header-Injection
function safe( $name ) {
   return( str_ireplace(array( "\r", "\n", "%0a", "%0d", "Content-Type:", "bcc:","to:","cc:" ), "", $name ) );
}
```

You can use `var_dump` to see the contents of the variables while you're working on the code.

**Instead of this**

```
echo "<script>window.location.href='http://www.tinfinitydesign.com/demo/charolette/donate-with-gift-aid/'</script>";
```

**Use this**

```
header('Location: http://www.tinfinitydesign.com/demo/charolette/donate-with-gift-aid/'); exit;
```

The `echo` approach sends JavaScript to the client which must be interpreted and executed, using `header` relieves the browser of reading the content and tells it to get a different page.
Apologies if this is too verbose.